# Is it possible to map °7 to { on Linux system wide?

Tags: linux, debian, keyboard, gnome, xmodmap

On a German keyboard, typing { is pretty cumbersome. So in VIM, I mapped the key sequence "°7" to "{" by having this line in my vimrc:

```
imap ⁷ {
```

This turned out to be super useful.

Is there a way to do this system wide on a Linux (Debian) system?

Comment: There are several ways to modify the keyboard layout system-wide; for example, I am using a US keyboard layout with an additional modifier for äöüÄÖÜß via `xmodmap`, so I can type `[]{}\|` easily. Note that this maps *keys*, not character sequences; mapping character sequences will probably need a custom program or a modified "input method" like those used for Chinese or Japanese.

Comment: @dirkt: That is the problem. I want to map a sequence.

Comment: Then I guess the simplest way is to read up on [input methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_input_methods_for_Unix_platforms) and make your own. Key/character sequences can be to some degree handled in the keyboard layout parts, but probably not in the generality you need them.